# Looking for an ssh client with support for background image

Tags: ssh

I am looking for a Windows ssh client (like putty) that can support setting a background image. I looked and found one called KiTTY which claims to support it when you modify it's config file (adding "backgroundimage=yes" to it), but when I do the settings all seem to break, and even when I undo my changes it seems to be broken until I delete the config file and let it rebuild itself. I was wondering if there was any alternative ssh clients that support this feature or if anyone knows how to properly configure KiTTY to support this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my goal using Hyper. I found a plugin for it called hyper-background which allowed me to set my own image as the background for the hyper terminal, and then I just use the ssh command built into windows to ssh into my remote machines. I just wanted it to look cool and now it does, seems to have the functionality I need. For anyone in the future who wants to do this, here's my guide:

Install hyper: https://hyper.is/

Open the config file (click the menu on top left, edit, preferences)

at the bottom you'll see a line: plugins: [],
change it to: plugins: ["hyper-background"],

above that you'll see a } closing curly brace
the line above that you put backgroundImage: "path/to/image"
be sure to put the path in quotation marks.

Then, finally, restart the client and your image will be there!
if you'd like to ssh in windows cmd, it goes like this:
ssh username@address

Hope this helps someone